# Enumeration yielded no results in WEB API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-web-api

I have a simple code.

```
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        using (var db = new AppDBContext())
        {
            var task = (from act in db.Activities select act);
            return Ok(task.ToList());
        }
    }
```

When I am debugging I am getting `Enumeration yielded no results` but there is 200 records when i execute it in database.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing silly mistake.

My wrong code

```
    public AppDBContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }
```

I thought `DefaultConnection` is a connection string. but when i changed it to my databasename `TaskFiveDB4` every thing is fine now.

Correct code

```
    public AppDBContext()
        : base("TaskFiveDB4", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }
```